# the maximum of two random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

The maximum of two random varibles $X$ and $Y$ is:

$$Z=\max\{X,Y\}=
\begin{cases}
X & \text{if } X \geq Y \\
Y & \text{if } Y \geq X
\end{cases}$$

I don't understand. So if I roll two dice, and let the first dice to be $X=\{1,\dots,6\}$ and second to be $Y=\{1,\dots,6\}$, and let $Z$ to be the maximum of the two. How do I define $Z$ then?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is, since you seem to have included the answer in the gray box. (I will say: usually you make the cases mutually exclusive, which these aren't since if $X=Y$ both of the "if" statements will be true.  I would personally change the second if to be $X<Y$.)

Comment: Perhaps your question is about what the distribution of $Z$ will be? If so, perhaps you should draw the 6-by-6 box of outcomes and look at patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe Z via its Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF):
$$P(Z\leq z) = P(\max(X,Y)\leq z) = P(X\leq z\text{ and }Y\leq z)$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(Z\leq z)=P(X\leq z\text{ and }Y\leq z)=P(X\leq z)P(Y\leq z)$.

You can think of it as having a machine which realizes both X and Y and then compares the realizations and outputs the bigger one.

As for the specific case with two independent dice on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $X$, $Y$, we have 
$P(Y\leq y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 1,& y\geq6 \\ \lfloor y \rfloor /6, &y\geq 0 \\ 0, y\leq 0 \end{array} \right.$ and identically for $P(X\leq x)$.

Plug this into the formula given prior to get the CDF of $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

If we define $Z$ as tabstop suggested above, we could write

$$\begin{aligned}\ P(Z=z) = P\left[((X=z)\cap(Y\leq z))\cup\left(X<z)\cap(Y=z)\right)\right] \\ \ = P(X=z) \cdot P(Y\leq z) + P(X<z)\cdot P(Y=z) \\ \ = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{z}{6}+\frac{z-1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}  \\ \ = \frac{2z-1}{36} \end{aligned} $$

If we make a $6\times 6$ table with the numbers $1$ through $6$ running the columns and the rows, and fill each entry in the table with the max of its column and row index, then we can see that the above fraction describes the distribution of $Z$.